# Using Handsontable with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, handsontable

When shimming Handsontable with requirejs I keep getting the following error and stack trace

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM18361 handsontable.full.js:20729 
unformatNumeral                                 VM18361 handsontable.full.js:21325
numeral.fn.Numeral.unformat                     VM18361 handsontable.full.js:21325
numeral                                         VM18361 handsontable.full.js:21037
```

This happens even with the examples from http://handsontable.com/.

My requirejs config and the module using handsontable look like this

```
require.config({                                                                                                                                         
 paths: {
   handsontable : '/js/dependencies/handsontable.full'                                                                               
},                                                                              
shim: {                                                                            
  'handsontable': {                                                             
    deps: ['jquery'],                                                           
    exports: 'Handsontable'                                                     
  }
}                                                                         

define(['handsontable'], function(Handsontable) { 
  var data = [
    ['', 'Maserati', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes', 'Mini', 'Mitsubishi'],
    ['2009', 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ['2010', 3, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ['2011', 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ['2012', 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151]
  ];

  var container = document.getElementById('example');

  var config = {
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
  };

  var hot = new Handsontable(container, config); 
});
```

Does anyone else experience this problem?

For now, the only solution I can see is including handsontable as a global object (circumventing the whole purpose of requirejs of managing dependencies).

I'd appreciate a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code which gives the error?

Comment: This looks like some problem of Handsontable internal API when using with requireJS, you should report them.. Your code is correct and error given by you mentions code inside handsontable, means you have already got the object correct from RequireJS

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to report an issue before I was sure I didn't mess something up in my own code.

Comment: could you log the content of container and config? is it what you expected?

Comment: Both container and config look normal. Pretty much the same exact code worked fine before I started using require.js on the project.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that you are using the full version of Handsontable, which includes dependencies, such as Numeral.js.  Since some of the dependencies are AMD compliant, i.e. there is a call to **define()**, you end up with the reference to Numeral.js and not Handsontable.

To use it correctly, you'll need to use just **bare distribution** file, handsontable.js, and include all the dependencies required for that version of Handsontable.  Something like this:

```
require.config({                                                                                                                                         
  paths: {
    handsontable : '/js/dependencies/handsontable'                                                                               
  },                                                                              
  shim: {                                                                            
    'handsontable': {                                                             
      deps: ['moment', 'pikaday', 'zeroclipboard'],                                                           
      exports: 'Handsontable'                                                     
    }
  }
})
```

I'm not sure which version of Handsontable you are using, the current version, 0.20.3, depends on moment, pikaday, and zeroclipboard.  See the [dist/READEME.md](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/tree/master/dist) for more information.